# UITableView Edit Mode Textfield

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have triggered an EditMode in `UITableView`, but I found that all my `UILabel` and a `UITextField` on the left are not shown in the correct position. How can I fix this. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: It works, but is it possible to implement in a grouped TableView?

Answer (score 0):

you have taken grouped TableView and added subvies on cell.

Need to add custom Objects always on Content View.